# Does Community Evaluation make sense for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, review

A “Community Evaluation” queue just appeared on the review page. It seems one of the main reasons for that queue is to compare each question with other sources on the internet for that same question:

> Review the question and its answers and compare them to information available from other online sources.

The problem is, all questions on CR are unique, there is nothing to compare them to. What does this mean for the Community Evaluation queue? Is it completely useless for CR? Or should we just focus on the general quality of answers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, this one is a bit of a stretch, isn't it?

For the moment, please focus on the quality of the answers. I will review the results once the evaluation is over and see if it's going to make sense to run another one, ever.

---

We've disabled future self-evaluations on Code Review to avoid confusion. It really doesn't make much sense to be comparing questions and answers here with other sites on the Internet.

Thank you everyone who participated in this round, though. Your feedback has been helpful.

Comment: I didn't understand at first what it was, so my first submissions only evaluate questions (and say they're not too good, since they're only [sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))... Sorry. By the way, will we know about the results of the evaluation?

Comment: @QuentinPradet Yes, I'll come back with some feedback on it. We got a few sites to review, so it might take a bit, but I promise it'll happen. :)

Comment: Should we still hope for those evaluation results? Thanks!

Comment: For reference, we got [awesome feedback](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-is-code-review-doing-right-now?cb=1) recently from Grace Note.