# Specify the [review] meta-tag, or burninate it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, meta

[Three questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) have used the [review](/questions/tagged/review) tag here on Meta CR so far. I find however that this tag is very vague. Is it about the review queues, is it about Code Reviewing itself (which is what the entire site is about), or is it something entirely different?

The questions currently using this tag are:

- [Is there a way to force the review of a suggested edit?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1076/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-review-of-a-suggested-edit)
- [Should you edit someone else's code in a question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/should-you-edit-the-code-in-a-question)
- [Does Community Evaluation make sense for Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/does-community-evaluation-make-sense-for-code-review)

I find this tag completely useless at the moment, since it doesn't specify what kind of review we're talking about.

Comment: slightly [on-topic](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/786/correct-edit-rejection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) exists on MSO with the following description:

> For questions about the /review path where users can view and act on
>   posts by other users that the system thinks may need attention.

I can make this change myself.  I can also add the wiki, which describes each of the queues (which is what this tag refers to).  Rep is not gained from suggested edits on this Meta, and there are fewer people around who monitor this Meta queue.

Also, it appears that Meta tags don't burninate themselves.  Take a look at the very last page of tags, and you'll see some older tags without questions.